# nginx rewrite rules for lithium php framework

Tags: nginx, rewrite, php-fpm

I have been trying to get `lithium` running with Nginx with no success. The directory structure of `lithium` is like this

```
lithium
  |-> app libraries .htaccess
      |-> webroot .htacess --other directories
           |-> index.php .htaccess --other files
```

I copied the `lithium` folder into my `/var/www/`. The path of lithium is `/var/www/lithium/`

Now I set up the rewrite rules this way in my `nginx.conf`

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root /var/www/;

    location /lithium {
       rewrite ^/$ /app/webroot/ break;
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /app/webroot/$1 break;
    }

    location /lithium/app {
       rewrite ^/$ /webroot/ break;
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /webroot/$1 break;
     }

    location /lithium/app/webroot {
       if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;
        }
     }
 ...then my php and other configurations
```

But nginx always throws a `404` error. Why is that happening?

I also tried this

```
server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;
            root /var/www/;

location /lithium {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/lithium/(.+)$ /lithium/app/webroot/$1 last;
            break;
            }
        }

        location /lithium/app/webroot {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/lithium/app/webroot/(.+)$ /lithium/app/webroot/index.php?url=$1 last;
            break;
        }
    }
...then my php and other configurations
```

But again there is a `404` error.

**Edit**

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10617120/535962) i changed my server's root to `/var/www/lithium/app/webroot` so my nginx conf looks like this

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name localhost;

        root   /var/www/lithium/app/webroot;
        access_log /var/log/lithium/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/lithium/error.log warn;

        index  index.php index.html;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$
        {
          .. ...
           ......

}
```

now i can see lithium's home but when i go to lithium's test dashboard which is `http://localhost/test` it again shows lithium's home instead of the test dashboard.When i use apache and go to url `http://localhost/test` it shows me the `test dashboard`. So the nginx rewrite rules are still not completely correct.More if i point `root` to `lithium's webroot` i cannot access other directories in my `/var/www/`

**EDITED AGIAN**

This is my complete server block

```
server { 
    server_name  lithium;
    root   /var/www/lithium/app/webroot;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/lith.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/lith.error.log;

    listen       127.0.0.2:80;
    rewrite_log on;

    # rewrite rules for lithium
    location / {
            index  index.php index.html;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri&$args;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            #include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
    }
}
```

I am using php 5.4.3. as php-fpm. I tried doing whats mentioned at lithium's official site [here](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/configuration/php.wiki) but i dont get this line

```
cp -f sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm /etc/init.d/php-fpm
```

which location is `sapi` referring to? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste the PHP configuration block (and any files included in there)?

Answer (score 1):

It'd be simpler to just point to webroot using `root /var/www/lithium/app/webroot`.

Or you can do the following.

```
root /var/www
```

then use `try_files` instead of ugly `if`'s:

```
index  index.php index.html;

location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}

location lithium/app/webroot/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /lithium/app/webroot/index.php?$args;
}

location /lithium/app/ {
    rewrite ^/lithium/app/(.*)$ /lithium/app/webroot/$1;
}

location /lithium/ {
    rewrite ^/lithium/(.*)$ /lithium/app/webroot/$1;
}

location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /lithium/app/webroot/$1;
}
```

Don't forget to protect the other directories.

Comment: I did as above and now i can see lithium's home but when i go to lithium's test dashboard which is `http://localhost/test` it again shows lithium's home instead of the `test dashboard`.When i use apache and go to url `http://localhost/test` it shows me the `test dashboard` So the rewrite rules are still not comletely correct.More if i point `root` to `lithium's webroot` i cannot access other directories in my `/var/www/`

Comment: I've edited it, can you try?

Comment: I tried as you suggested but now the url `http://localhost/test` gives a 404 error

Comment: I changed it, and mostly removed the `break` which prevent it from going into try_files I guess.

Comment: changing to the above rewrite rules gives `500` error

Answer (score 1):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

You aren't passing the URI through to Lithium -- you're appending the query string, which is empty. You probably want the following:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri&$args;
```

Assuming that Lithium expects to be called with `index.php?uri=/test` (which is what your original configuration implies).

**Edit**: The [Lithium wiki](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/configuration/servers/nginx.wiki) does suggest the top [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) line, which implies that it inspects the FastCGI variables to determine the URL to serve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not setting the path correct.  Try running just a basic nginx config: http://lithify.me/docs/manual/configuration/servers/nginx.wiki

Turning on php errors can also be helpful.  Configuration errors like setting the path to the lithium libraries are not obvious unless you have php errors turn on.

Comment: How do i get it running under localhost?

Comment: @lovesh: nginx needs fastcgi to run php files, look at the `location ~ \.php$` part in the lithium manual example that cgarvis linked to.

Comment: here is the nginx wiki page for configuring fastcgi with nginx http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample

Comment: @Oerd my problem is not running php with nginx. I am able to do that. The problem is with rewrite rules

Answer (score 0):

```
#include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
```

You're not including the configuration file which sets most of the FastCGI variables passed to PHP, so Lithium is probably not able to determine which URL is being requested. Uncomment this line and move it above the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` line so that your block looks like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
}
```

Comment: i uncommented that line but same 404 error. Also in the url bar it show the url `http://lithium/lithium/test` for the test dashboard. I manually changed the url to `http://lithium/test` but still the 404 error